# Moving Community Site from Site Pages to (Publishing) Pages

Tags: master-page, publishing-site, branding, community-site, sitepages

For a project I'm working on I want to enable the Community features of SharePoint. This works like a charm, but the community pages are created as Site Pages.

Is there a way to convert Site Pages to Publishing Pages, or to assign Site Pages to the Site Master Page (and page layout) instead of the System Master Page?

In case this is not possible, are there any best practises for re-creating all the pages manually and adjust the links to the specific pages?

Answer (score 0):

At your community site , You should try to enable `publishing features` then recreate the old pages manually with the required page layout .

**To enable publishing features**

- On the Site Settings page under Site Collection Administration, click Site collection features.
- On the Site Features page, scroll down to SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure and click Activate.
- Again On the Site Settings page, in the Site Actions section, click Manage site features.
- On the Site Features page, next to SharePoint Server Publishing, click Activate.

Comment: I've already enabled the publishing features and made a start to re-create the old pages with the required page layout. However, I'm not sure how I can adjust all the links that are automatically created within the web parts. For example, clicking on a discussion to see the details and to show the newly created Topic page.